# Excel workbook cell locking seems to vary between PCs

Tags: excel

I have an Excel 2007 workbook with multiple detail worksheets (let's call them Detail1, Detail 2, Detail 3 etc.) and a Summary worksheet which uses formulae to total some of the cell values from the detail sheets. Most of the cells on the detail sheets are locked so it's possible to enter values into only a few cells on each sheet; let's say those unlocked cells are A1:A10 and D20:K20. The workbook does not contain any VBA code.

On my three PCs everything works as described above and it does on several other people's PCs but we have a couple of users where there's a problem. They can enter data into cells D20:K20 on all the detail sheets but for them A1:A10 cells are all non-enterable. If they eMail the file to a user with a non-problem PC it's fine again but if the file is then returned to the problem PC the issue reappears.

The only obvious "difference" about the problem PCs is that they're in France with French Windows / Office set-ups whereas my mine and most of the other users are English. We've sent it to a couple of users in Spain with Spanish set-ups and it was OK there.

I'm stumped, so over to you guys !

Answer (score 0):

Is the sheet protected using a password?  There used to be (still are?) some differences in the French version relating to strength of password protection which may or may not be relevant...

From: http://lastbit.com/msohelp/wordexcel.htm

"In new Office versions beginning with XP all three variants are supported and the default variant is "Office 97/2000 compatible protection". Most documents are protected using this protection mode. The French version of Office always uses Weak protection (as the French laws limit the strength of encryption software)."

I think this relates to the workbook open password though, and it doesn't explain the observation that only some cells are affected.

Comment: Thanks, Tim. There's no workbook-open password but the detail worksheets ARE password-protected so OK we'll try without a password (will probably have to wait until Monday for a response) but, as you say, the real mystery is that only some of the cells are affected by the problem.

Comment: No, and before you ask, there's none on the cells that do work as planned either !